# How significant was Trump's undisclosed 19.8M loan relative to his total net worth?

Tags: united-states, donald-trump

Title sort of says it all.  There is plenty of talk about Trump having a loan to a foreign power he never disclosed.  I'm just wondering how big was that loan, at least relative to Trump's finances as a whole.  Admittedly that's hard to know since Trump's net worth is pretty hard to pin down and there are allegations of his inflating it.  Still can anyone give me a ball park.  Was this real money, or pocket change in Trump's eyes?

Comment: Does it really matter how much the loan is compared to his net worth? That is still 19.8 Million dollars that he received from a foreign source with ties to North Korea that he did not disclose. This is not about the amount of money received but that it was money from a foreign source that was not disclosed as it was required to be.

Comment: @JoeW I have no doubt some of his supports will claim it did.  I personally am not making any claim that it does or doesn't matter, I'm simply asking what amount it is.  I'm asking only a question of raw fact, not about rather the loan was morally or legally significant.

Comment: Because Trump Organization is a private entity, which is not publicly traded, its net worth is not known even to its proprietors.  It can only be estimated and the accurate estimate changes daily and depends on many market forces.  Which makes this question both a matter of opinion and unanswerable, based on the sources available to the public.  Both are reasons for closing.

Comment: Trump's net worth is allegedly negative, so how do you measure that percentage?

Answer (score 5):

- In absolute terms, not very significant.  $19.8M is a fraction of Trump's uncertain, oft-inflated fortune, which [Forbes currently estimates at $3.2B](https://www.forbes.com/sites/danalexander/2022/09/27/the-definitive-networth-of-donaldtrump/).  The proportional amount involved **is** relevant to any influence a third party might have wanted to pursue with it.  It is **not** relevant to compliance with disclosure laws. Per [Vanity Fair](https://www.vanityfair.com/news/2022/12/donald-trump-undisclosed-debt):

> Trump eliminated the debt five and a half months into his tenure as president, according to the documents. He seems to have acted with some urgency to wipe the liability off his balance sheet. From 2011 to 2016, the documents show that the balance stayed static at $19.8 million. **Paperwork capturing Trump’s financial picture as of June 30, 2017, five months into his presidency, appears to show that the balance had dropped to $4.3 million, $15.5 million less than it had been a year earlier.** Trump got rid of the debt altogether shortly after that. “Daewoo was bought out of its position on July 5, 2017,” the documents say, without specifying who exactly paid off the loan.

- "Ties to North Korea" is a bit misleading.  Daewoo was one of the major SK Chaebols and had fingers in many many pies (one of which was oil in Myanmar).  Operating in NK, under the economic rapprochement program in the 1990s which saw IIRC a special industrial zone established in NK, is hardly the stuff of opprobrium, *unless you disagree with **any** rapprochement and normalization with Kim's murderous regime*.  It *was* SK official policy, aiming to promote peace.
- This seems "merely" another one of Trump's endless cases of lies, omissions and underhanded dealings *that break laws*.  It would sink any other politician, under any sane voter base.  But as a stable genius once said "I could shoot someone on 5th Avenue and get away with it".  Or, flip side, if he jumped in and saved a toddler from a gator in a Florida golf course pond, many would still not give him the time of day.
- Or, was it even illegal?  Even that is not super clear.  [Forbes, who broke the original story](https://www.forbes.com/sites/danalexander/2022/12/04/trump-owed-hidden-debt-while-in-office):

> There is a chance that Trump’s omission may have been legal, nonetheless. Although officials have to list personal loans on their financial disclosures, the law does not require them to include loans to their companies, unless they are personally liable for the loans. The Trump Organization documents do not specify whether the former president, who owned 100% of the entities responsible for the debt, personally guaranteed the liability, **leaving it unclear whether he broke the law or merely took advantage of a loophole**.

The problem is that sending him to jail or the like would be construed as an act of political persecution by a significant proportion of the US population, unless it is so obviously criminal in nature that very few people disagree.  *This* doesn't seem the case here.  So he is likely going to remain somewhat "above the law", until he does something causing his support to drop, as happened to Nixon.

Edit:  Trump is not avoiding going to jail because he's wealthy as such.  He is currently avoiding going to jail because putting him in jail would be setting off a political thermonuclear bomb in the US.  **He could be a lot less wealthy, that's not the metric.  The metric is the 48% of people who voted for him in 2020.  And the sizable proportion who still support him, after Jan 6th.**  Another metric is his fizzle in the midterms.

Comment: The part of the answer about "The problem is that sending him..." etc. is not relevant to the question asked and should be removed.  The last bullet point is an irrelevant smear, and should be removed. The first bullet point is a correction of another smear, and is also irrelevant and should be removed.

Comment: The quote from Vanity Fair does not address the question either, since it deals with paying down the loan rather than the relative fraction of Trump's assets.

Comment: I consider it to be relevant to the likely *outcome* of this particular event - which is very likely to remain limited.  He's got many legal issues, this is just one more.  It sounds impressive - and it is, in absolute legal terms.  But this is Trump it's likely going to drag out for years.  The Q in general asking:  is this this a big deal?  That prognostic is part of my answer.  One side of the aisle is seething sure.  But the Fox News readers are hardly gonna care.  They don't even care that much about his Constitution suspension pseudo-Tweet.

Comment: I have to agree with @bobafit  You *can* have a bulletpoint stating that not disclosing such a loan is illegal and point to the specific law, but just taking it for granted as illegal isn't proof.  Further you can state that you don't think anything would come out of it given historical track record (I agree), but the manner in which you did it involved attacks on Trump.  It doesn't matter what your, my, or anyone's views of him are, answers that show bias against the person they are about are inherently less trustworthy, and as such your answer would be stronger if you focused on facts only.

Comment: @bobafit I agree with your first comment, but I think the vanity fair quote is still relevant.  Given how hard it is to judge Trump's actual worth, and the further question of the liquidity of said worth, demonstrating that the loan was apparently not too hard to pay off, since it was rapidly payed off, does give some indicator of how significant it was to Trump's overall bottom line.  It's not as good as I would like, but I knew asking the question it would be hard to give a good answer giving the unknowns of trumps actual net worth so I'll take what I can get.

Comment: @dsollen I did not point to any particular law - I am not a lawyer.  I answered your Q and noted concerns I had about the characterization of Daewoo as "NK-linked".  That's a very simplistic way to describe a massive conglomerate that had some, justifiable, links 15-20 years ago.  Unfortunately all the press just requoted it like that.   I don't like Trump much but honestly there's not all that much fire to this smoke *from what we can see at the present*.  A comment characterizing it as a "bribe"?  Laughable.